# Android : How to differentiate commands used for StartSevice()

Tags: android, service, android-intent

I have a questions here. I wanted to communicate to my service from my broadcast receiver. So I used the StartSevice(intent) method. In the service side the OnStartCommand() is called everytime I called StartService(). I just need to know how can i recognize in the onStartCommand() from where it is called from?

I hope I am clear in my question. If not please let me clarify...

Comment: you can putExtra in the intent you startService with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really check where you're called from, but you can do something a little bit related.  You can specify certain tags in the Intent that you pass to the onStartCommand().   Notice that onStartCommand() takes an intent as its argument, this will be the intent that you sent.  Whenever you send an intent to start the service from your broadcast receiver, you can specify certain "extras" in your intent and then use get those in your service.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent, int, int)

By the way, the use case you give seems to line up more with an IntentService than a regular service.  This is a service which does what you're doing already: it sits there and waits for intents to be fired at it, and then reacts accordingly:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html

Answer (score 0):

In the onStartCommand method, the Intent you used to start service is passed as an argument.

```
onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
```

So you can add Extras to intent to distinct where from it is called.

```
 intent.putExtra("From", "MainScreen");
```